# Crystal Report doesn't seem in HTTPS page

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, crystal-reports

I have a CrsytalReportView in my asp.net page.I am setting the ReportSource of the CrystalReportViewer in Page_Load event. ReportViewer shows report data in the page when I start page by running visual studio. And I published my web site in IIS over http and everything works fine. But nothing is showing in Report page after changing binding to **HTTPS** for the web site  from IIS.

Here is some code:

1.My Report Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterMain.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeBehind="ReportPageMain.aspx.cs" Inherits="RPS_ArchiveEditor_NEW.ReportPageMain" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
        Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph_Body" runat="server">
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewerMain" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true"
            HasPrintButton="False" HasExportButton="False" HasDrillUpButton="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPrintReport" CssClass="PrintReportButton" OnClick="btnPrintReport_Click" Text="Çap et" />
        <input type="button" id="btnGoToDefaultPage" class="PrintReportButton" value="Əsas səhifə" onclick="window.location.href='Default.aspx'" />
    </asp:Content>

2. Page_Load event



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        if (Ajax.RoleIsAdmin())
            crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("rptMainGridView.rpt"));
        else
            crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("rptUserGridView.rpt"));
        // in this session have data, I'm absolutely sure.
        List<PersonDetailsForPrint> perDetsForPrintList = Session["perDetForPrint"] as List<PersonDetailsForPrint>;
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(perDetsForPrintList);
        CrystalReportViewerMain.ReportSource = crystalReport;
        Session["ReportSource"] = crystalReport;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my problem. There was not  **aspnet_client** folder in a physical directory of my website. I have registered IIS for .NET Framework v4.0.30319 version:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```